# Are there any IP allocation algorithms to allocate subnets efficiently from an IP address space?

Tags: algorithm, networking, ip-address

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to allocate ip-address from a universal address space. I have a backend database to store the allocated subnets from which I can calculate the available ip-address space. I want to know if there any existing algorithms to do this.

Edit:
The user can decide whether she wants a contiguous address or not. The algorithm will allocate the addresses based on the users configuration object and the pre-defined set of rules.

Defragmentation is a different usecase. The administrator can defragment the address space whenever he wants. This is not under consideration now.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have one continuous range, or many smaller ranges? Will ranges be re-allocated so you have to worry about fragmenting or will addresses that have been allocated once remain allocated indefinitely?

Comment: Given those specifications, you could just assign every address request the start portion of the smallest space that fulfills the request. That way, contiguous requests will contribute little to fragmentation, and address requests that don't have to be fulfilled contiguously can be used to fill "gaps" in the available address space. As a data structure that maintains the available addresses as contiguous intervals, you could use an interval tree since IP addresses are basically integers.

Comment: sounds like what DHCP does, but DHCP doesn't support contiguous addrees allocation, and considers more about communication. you can look at [wiki about DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP) and [RFC2131:2.2 Dynamic allocation of network addresses](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2131#page-12)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a first-fit-decreasing (FFD) heuristic.

It's useful for the following problem statement:

(a) you have a number of subnets you can allocate from (these are the bins), and
(b) you have a number of demands you want to satisfy (these are the items you put in the bins).

This seems to match the OP's case.

If interest is expressed in this heuristic, I'll elaborate, as it's a bit of a task to write down and I don't want to bother further if it's not necessary.